# How to make slider arrows taller

Tags: html, css, wordpress, slider, arrows

I want to create my slider's arrows taller. I want them to be stretched vertically. I use WordPress plugin called SmartSlider. I have already tried to use CSS :

```
.nextend-arrow{
    width:100px!important;
    height:100px!important;
}
```

I have found it on the plugin's website. When I change only height to be greater than width arrows remain in the previous size...
I also tried using :

```
.nextend-arrow{
        height:100%!important;
    }
```

This is the previous arrow (from Chrome inspect):

```
<div data-ssleft="0+15" data-sstop="height/2-previousheight/2" id="n2-ss-7-arrow-previous" class="n2-ss-widget n2-ss-widget-display-desktop n2-ss-widget-display-tablet n2-ss-widget-display-mobile n2-style-15840d24d130269e6b64e6608dab2b08-heading nextend-arrow n2-ow nextend-arrow-previous  nextend-arrow-animated-fade n2-ib" style="position: absolute; width: 22.4px; height: 280px; top: 2.5px; left: 15px;" role="button" aria-label="Previous slide" tabindex="0"><img class="n2-ow" data-no-lazy="1" data-hack="data-lazy-src" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMzIiIGhlaWdodD0iMzIiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAzMiAzMiIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIj48cGF0aCBkPSJNMTEuNDMzIDE1Ljk5MkwyMi42OSA1LjcxMmMuMzkzLS4zOS4zOTMtMS4wMyAwLTEuNDItLjM5My0uMzktMS4wMy0uMzktMS40MjMgMGwtMTEuOTggMTAuOTRjLS4yMS4yMS0uMy40OS0uMjg1Ljc2LS4wMTUuMjguMDc1LjU2LjI4NC43N2wxMS45OCAxMC45NGMuMzkzLjM5IDEuMDMuMzkgMS40MjQgMCAuMzkzLS40LjM5My0xLjAzIDAtMS40MmwtMTEuMjU3LTEwLjI5IiBmaWxsPSIjMzcyZjJmIiBvcGFjaXR5PSIwLjUxIiBmaWxsLXJ1bGU9ImV2ZW5vZGQiLz48L3N2Zz4=" alt="previous arrow" style="width: 100%;"></div>

<img class="n2-ow" data-no-lazy="1" data-hack="data-lazy-src" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMzIiIGhlaWdodD0iMzIiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAzMiAzMiIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIj48cGF0aCBkPSJNMTEuNDMzIDE1Ljk5MkwyMi42OSA1LjcxMmMuMzkzLS4zOS4zOTMtMS4wMyAwLTEuNDItLjM5My0uMzktMS4wMy0uMzktMS40MjMgMGwtMTEuOTggMTAuOTRjLS4yMS4yMS0uMy40OS0uMjg1Ljc2LS4wMTUuMjguMDc1LjU2LjI4NC43N2wxMS45OCAxMC45NGMuMzkzLjM5IDEuMDMuMzkgMS40MjQgMCAuMzkzLS40LjM5My0xLjAzIDAtMS40MmwtMTEuMjU3LTEwLjI5IiBmaWxsPSIjMzcyZjJmIiBvcGFjaXR5PSIwLjUxIiBmaWxsLXJ1bGU9ImV2ZW5vZGQiLz48L3N2Zz4=" alt="previous arrow" style="width: 100%;">
```

Img is inside that div.

And image:
[Slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KLO8.jpg)

I want these arrows to be almost as tall as the slider, but thin as now.

This is my first post, sorry for my poor language and thanks for Your help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide enough code to replicate the problem - see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: But looking at the image, it's width is 100% and seems to be a square so you need to change both the width and height of your nextend arrow class for the image to be taller (the height of the image will grow automatically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a container for them. Give the container a `position: relative;`, the arrows a `position: absolute;`, then you can use 100%.

The reason `height: 100%;` is not working right now is the browser doesn't know what to compare 100% to, since there is no given `height` for the parent element.

Comment: True, I'm new here, sorry.